# docx no respeta los margenes señalados

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

tengo un simple código para crear un documento de word con ciertos parámetros. Le puse márgenes y tamaño de página pero al crear el documento, no los respeta. Crea un documento gigante y sin márgenes. Copié el código de un tutorial y compila, así que no sé que estoy haciendo mal.

```
import mysql.connector
import docx
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.shared import Cm
results=[(1, 'AA634SP', 'Mario', 25814334, 'maiz', 5,  ('5.000'), 'Milazo', '', '', 'Balarca',  (2022, 12, 16), '10:33:14 AM', '',  ('5.000'),  ('46000.000'),  ('-45995.000'),
 ('0.000')), (2, 'LOP13F55', 'Mario', 25814334, 'maiz', 100,  ('100.000'), 'Metalúrgia', '', '', 'Balarca',  (2022, 12, 13), '10:33:50 AM', '',  ('1000.000'),  ('13600.000'),  ('-12600.000'), ('900.000')), (3, 'LML54PS', 'Mario', 25814334, 'hierro', 666,  ('4000.000'), '', 'El tunal', '667', 'Balarca',  (2022, 12, 12), '10:34:31 AM', '',  ('4000.000'),  ('46000.000'),  ('-42000.000'),  ('0.000')), (4, 'LOP1234', 'Mario', 25814334, 'hierro', 8,  ('100.000'), 'Metalúrgia', '', '', 'Balarca',  (2022,
12, 30), '10:51:38 AM', '',  ('1000.000'),  ('13600.000'),  ('-12600.000'),  ('900.000')), (6, 'LOP12345', 'Miguel', 28969334, 'pollo', 5,  ('1000.000'), 'Metalúrgia', '', '', 'Balarca',  (2023, 1, 3), '12:41:29 PM', '',  ('1000.000'),  ('46000.000'),  ('-45000.000'),  ('0.000')), (7, 'CLAH555', 'Miguel', 28969334, 'aluminio', 6,  ('1000.000'), 'Milazo', '', '', 'Balarca',  (2023, 1, 3), '12:42:08 PM', '',  ('1000.000'),  ('1000.000'),  ('-45000.000'),  ('0.000')), (8, 'REF324J', 'Edgar', 11725788,
'Trigo', 5,  ('1000.000'), 'Milazo', '', '', 'Balarca',  (2023, 1, 3), '12:46:46 PM', '',  ('1000.000'),  ('0.000'),  ('0.000'),  ('0.000')), (9, 'REF325J', 'Miguel', 28969334, 'maiz', 6,  ('512.000'), 'Milazo', '', '', 'Balarca',  (2023, 1, 3), '12:47:16 PM', '',  ('1000.000'),  ('1000.000'),  ('0.000'),  ('0.000'))]

# Crear un nuevo documento de Word
document = Document()

# Obtener la primera sección del documento
section = document.sections[0]
section.page_width = Inches(8.5)
section.page_height = Inches(11)
section.top_margin = Inches(0.75)
section.bottom_margin = Inches(0.75)
section.left_margin = Inches(1.18)
section.right_margin = Inches(1.18)

# Agregar el membrete
header = section.header
header.add_paragraph('Membrete de la empresa')

# Recorrer los resultados de la consulta y agregar cada fila al documento
for row in results:
    for element in row:
        document.add_paragraph(str(element))
    document.add_paragraph('')

# Agregar la fecha a pie de página
footer = section.footer
parrafo = footer.add_paragraph('Fecha: ')
parrafo.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT

# Guardar el documento
document.save("document2.docx")
```

Comment: Si lo copiaste de un tutorial y al tipo del tutorial le "compila", es posible que el tutorial trabaje con una versión más vieja o nueva de python-docx (una versión donde left_margin, right_margin, etc, no existen y solo estás estableciendo atributos sin significado). Igual la documentación no me da indicios de que puede estar pasando. De hecho, pareciera que lo haces como lo indican. Agregarías el link del tutorial para ver mejor que puede estar pasando por favor?

Comment: Hola @DanteS., no fué un tutorial. Le pedí a chatgpt que me recomendara una librería para generar reportes. Me recomendó esta y me escribió el código, hice algunas pruebas y logré que me escribiera los datos uno por uno, pero no me carga los márgenes

Answer (score 0):

sections = self.doc.sections
for section in sections:
section.page_width = Inches(8.5)
section.page_height = Inches(11)
section.top_margin = Cm(0.95)
section.bottom_margin = Cm(1)
section.left_margin = Cm(3.5)
section.right_margin = Cm(3)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.